# 16-bit Eddystone UUID what values should contain?

Tags: protocols, beacon, eddystone

The eddystone prefix contains twice the 16-bit Eddystone UUID.
This value according the example on the protocol specification (https://github.com/google/eddystone/blob/master/protocol-specification.md) is:

0xFEAA

But I've seen beacons containing the value 0x3F3F. I didn't understand if the value 0xFEAA is not mandatory or can I put inside that field any value ?

Also I don't understand the reason why the protocol uses twice the 16-bit Eddystone UUID.
Once near the field:
"Complete list of 16-bit Service UUIDs data type value"
and another time near the field:
"Service Data data type value"

[image]

Comment: What makes you say it is sometimes 0x3F3F?

Comment: I used a minew beacon as a sample and with the binary editor i get 0x3F3F

Comment: So where does the binary editor get its byte sequence?  Can you show this byte sequence?  This might help explain what you are seeing.

Comment: I added the screenshot. This time i get 0xEFBF. What changed I cannot understand. The beacon starts after the 'S' (0x53).

Comment: Just because the Minew Beacon is advertising packets doesn't mean those packets are supposed to be Eddystone advertisements.  It may be part of a proprietary service (perhaps for configuration?) created by the manufacturer.